# How to compute $E[24]$ for $E: y^2=x^3-15x+22$

Tags: elliptic-curves

If I have an Elliptic curve $E: y^2=x^3-15x+22$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with CM from the imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ then how do I compute the $24$-torsion subgroup $E[24]$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

I know how to compute the $2,3$ and $4$-torsion subgroups using the following algorithm: if $P=(x,y)$ is a point on $E$ then if $2P=\mathcal{O}$ we have $y=0$. And, if $3P=\mathcal{O}$ then $x(2P)=x$ further if instead $4P=\mathcal{O}$ then $y(2P)=0$.

So, what should I do next? Compute $6$-torsion points by setting $y(3P)=0$? And, then in a similar way the $12$ and $24$-
torsion points?

Also, is there any software that allow us to compute $n$-torsion groups for large $n$?

Comment: I'm sure Magma and Sage can do this

Comment: @LukasHeger I don't know how to use those or how to write a program using those. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4):

Computing in this case means really computing. To see which is the complexity of the needed calculus, i am constrained to use some software helping me to get the answer quickly. When the answer stays here explicitly we can still argue if "easy / handy computations" may suffice.

In sage i am intializing the curve, asking for the $24$-division polynomial $f$ associated to it. In case of a nice information so far - we may still ask for the field where its roots live in, then make a base change and compute the generators (instead of computing all $24^2$ points). Well, instead of plotting the polynomial $f$ - which will soon have degree $289$, let us print the factors of $f$, or at least some information on them when they make the line explode to the right.

```
E = EllipticCurve(QQ, [-15, 22])
f = E.division_polynomial(24)
for fact, mul in f24.factor():
    info = ( str(fact) if fact.degree() <= 8 
             else f'factor of degree {fact.degree()}' )
    print(f'{info} with discriminant {ZZ(fact.discriminant()).factor()}')
```

We get so far:

```
x - 3 with discriminant 1
x - 2 with discriminant 1
x + 1 with discriminant 1
x^2 - 10*x + 13 with discriminant 2^4 * 3
x^2 - 4*x + 7 with discriminant -1 * 2^2 * 3
x^2 + 2*x - 11 with discriminant 2^4 * 3
x^3 - 9*x^2 + 51*x - 83 with discriminant -1 * 2^8 * 3^5
x^3 + 3*x^2 - 21*x + 25 with discriminant -1 * 2^8 * 3^3
x^4 + 4*x^3 - 66*x^2 + 148*x - 71 with discriminant 2^20 * 3^6
x^4 + 4*x^3 + 30*x^2 - 236*x + 313 with discriminant 2^20 * 3^7
x^6 + 18*x^5 - 141*x^4 + 428*x^3 - 1161*x^2 + 2658*x - 2507 with discriminant 2^44 * 3^19
x^8 - 40*x^7 + 268*x^6 - 952*x^5 + 1270*x^4 + 7592*x^3 - 40724*x^2 + 73400*x - 46703 with discriminant 2^88 * 3^30
x^8 - 16*x^7 + 172*x^6 - 592*x^5 + 454*x^4 - 2032*x^3 + 16876*x^2 - 37168*x + 25633 with discriminant 2^80 * 3^28
factor of degree 12 with discriminant 2^188 * 3^75
factor of degree 16 with discriminant 2^352 * 3^120
factor of degree 16 with discriminant 2^352 * 3^124
factor of degree 24 with discriminant 2^776 * 3^294
factor of degree 32 with discriminant 2^1408 * 3^504
factor of degree 48 with discriminant 2^3104 * 3^1164
factor of degree 96 with discriminant 2^12416 * 3^4632
```

And you really do not want to see (here) the last polynomial of degree $96$. One can compute of course closer information, so for the last question regarding a possible soft aimed to help, well sage is a free choice.

Here is as supplementary information what we can immediately compute, and may help for the asked purpose.

We can ask for the torsion points over $\Bbb Q$.

```
sage: [ T.xy() if T else 'O' for T in E.torsion_points() ]
[(-1, -6), (-1, 6), 'O', (2, 0), (3, -2), (3, 2)]
```

We have some polynomials of degree two listed as factors, discriminant is sometimes $3$ times a square, so it may be interesting to switch to the field $F=\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)=\Bbb Q(a)$, $a=\sqrt 3$. Then the given curve, seen over $F$ has...

```
R.<x> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
F.<a> = NumberField(x^2 - 3)
print(f'F is the field:\n{F}\n')
E = EllipticCurve(F, [-15, 22])
print(f'E has over F the torsion group:\n{E.torsion_subgroup()}\n')
print(f'Its generators are {E.torsion_subgroup().gens()}')
```

And the prints give the information:

```
F is the field:
Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^2 - 3

E has over F the torsion group:
Torsion Subgroup isomorphic to Z/6 + Z/2 
    associated to the Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + (-15)*x + 22
    over Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^2 - 3

Its generators are ((-2*a + 5 : -6*a + 12 : 1), (2 : 0 : 1))
```

Here, instead of getting $E[24]$, let us compute starting from $F$ the pieces $E[3]\subset E(\overline{\Bbb Q})$ and $E[2^k]\subset E(\overline{\Bbb Q})$, $k=1,2,3$ as far as possible.

```
sage: E.division_polynomial(3).factor()
(3) * (x - 3) * (x^3 + 3*x^2 - 21*x + 25)

sage: E.division_polynomial(2).factor()
(4) * (x - 2*a + 1) * (x - 2) * (x + 2*a + 1)

sage: E.division_polynomial(4).factor()
(8) * (x - 2*a + 1) * (x - 2) * (x + 2*a + 1) * (x^2 + (-4*a + 2)*x + 8*a - 11) 
    * (x^2 - 4*x + 7) * (x^2 + (4*a + 2)*x - 8*a - 11)
```

and for the $8$-division let us better take each factor one by one...

```
sage: for fact, mul in E.division_polynomial(8).factor():
....:     print(fact, 'with discriminant', F(fact.discriminant()).factor())
....: 
x - 2*a + 1 with discriminant 1
x - 2 with discriminant 1
x + 2*a + 1 with discriminant 1
x^2 + (-4*a + 2)*x + 8*a - 11 with discriminant (15*a + 26) * (-a)^2 * (-a + 1)^8
x^2 - 4*x + 7 with discriminant (-4*a - 7) * (-a)^2 * (-a + 1)^4
x^2 + (4*a + 2)*x - 8*a - 11 with discriminant (209*a + 362) * (-a)^2 * (-a + 1)^8
x^4 + (-4*a - 8)*x^3 + (48*a + 78)*x^2 + (-132*a - 248)*x + 104*a + 241
    with discriminant (296011017105*a + 512706121226) * (-a)^12 * (-a + 1)^36
x^4 + (4*a - 8)*x^3 + (-48*a + 78)*x^2 + (132*a - 248)*x - 104*a + 241
    with discriminant (109552575*a + 189750626) * (-a)^12 * (-a + 1)^36
x^8 + (-16*a + 8)*x^7 + (128*a - 116)*x^6 + (-240*a - 232)*x^5 
    + (-1376*a + 5398)*x^4 + (9232*a - 20104)*x^3 + (-24000*a + 31276)*x^2 
    + (31472*a - 21016)*x - 17248*a + 5041 
    with discriminant 
       (319156261898201133032451783177661812885799840920*a 
        + 552794861161443374798157973077388454680145589601)
       * (-a)^56 * (-a + 1)^176
x^8 + (16*a + 8)*x^7 + (-128*a - 116)*x^6 + (240*a - 232)*x^5
    + (1376*a + 5398)*x^4 + (-9232*a - 20104)*x^3 + (24000*a + 31276)*x^2
    + (-31472*a - 21016)*x + 17248*a + 5041
    with discriminant
        (12011126751796371544078833423566810504717197292016904*a
         + 20803881790261051311370607096723572357290287974786657)
        * (-a)^56 * (-a + 1)^176
sage:
```

Results were manually rearranged. Now let us exhibit the $3$-torsion. This is "hard enough" (to type). We ask for the corresponding division polynomial, which is of degree $3$, use $b$ for a "fixed symbolic root", so we expect to get a torsion point $T=(b,?)$, but the question mark involves taking the square root from $b^3 -15b+22$, denote it by $c$, so we have to extend $L=\Bbb Q(b)$ to $K=\Bbb Q(c)$. Over $K$ we have then at least a subgroup with $3^2$ elements with torsion order dividing $3$. Therin $3^2-1=8$ elements have order exactly $3$. Let us plot them in a final step...
Here is my dialog with the sage interpreter:

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve(QQ, [-15, 22])
sage: f = E.division_polynomial(3).factor()
sage: f
(3) * (x - 3) * (x^3 + 3*x^2 - 21*x + 25)

sage: L.<b> = NumberField(x^3 + 3*x^2 - 21*x + 25)
sage: (b^3 - 15*b + 22).is_square()
False
sage: # so we do not have an easy torsion point T = (b, ...) over L 

sage: RL.<y> = PolynomialRing(L)
sage: K.<c>  = L.extension(y^2 - (b^3 - 15*b + 22))

sage: EK = E.base_extend(K)
sage: EK.torsion_subgroup()
Torsion Subgroup isomorphic to Z/6 + Z/3 associated to the 
    Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + (-15)*x + 22 over 
    Number Field in c with defining polynomial y^2 + 3*b^2 - 6*b + 3 
    over its base field

sage: for T in EK.torsion_points():
....:     if T.order() == 3:
....:         print(T.xy())
....: 
(3, 2)
(3, -2)
((3/8*b^2 + 2*b - 27/8)*c - 1/2*b - 3/2, (3/8*b^2 + 3/2*b - 55/8)*c - 3/2*b^2 - 15/2*b + 18)
(b, c)
((-3/8*b^2 - 2*b + 27/8)*c - 1/2*b - 3/2, (3/8*b^2 + 3/2*b - 55/8)*c + 3/2*b^2 + 15/2*b - 18)
((3/8*b^2 + 2*b - 27/8)*c - 1/2*b - 3/2, (-3/8*b^2 - 3/2*b + 55/8)*c + 3/2*b^2 + 15/2*b - 18)
((-3/8*b^2 - 2*b + 27/8)*c - 1/2*b - 3/2, (-3/8*b^2 - 3/2*b + 55/8)*c - 3/2*b^2 - 15/2*b + 18)
(b, -c)
```

In the last loop with lots of prints we see the two expected torsion points $(b,\pm c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Find the two rational functions $f,g$ such that $(a,b)+(x,y)=(f(a,b,x,y),g(a,b,x,y))$.

Compose $24$ times to get the two rational functions such that $[24](x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$.

$(u(x,-y),v(x,-y))=[24](x,-y)=-[24](x,y)=-(u(x,y),v(x,y))=(u(x,y),-v(x,y))$ so $u(x,y)=u(x,-y)$. This implies that $u(x,y)$ will be a rational function solely in $x$. Write $u(x)=p(x)/q(x)$ with $p,q$ coprime polynomials.

The zeros of $q$ are the $c\ne \infty$ such that $u(c)=\infty$ ie. such that $[24](c,\sqrt{c^3-15c-22}) = O$.

So the zeros of $q(x)$ are the $x$ coordinates of the non-trivial $24$-torsion points.